# get_user_model doesn't return a value

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, model

as my first project in Django I am creating a todo app, that lets people log in and see their own tasks that they created. For that, I need to save author info in single task data.

From what I learned reading the documentation and doing lots of google-searching, the current approach is to use the get_user_model function from django.contrib.auth.

The problem is, that whenever I try to use it in my model, it seems to not get the username from the currently logged in user. While printing the form.errors to my console, the output is:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>added_by<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Seems like the get_user_model is not returning any value. Can anyone recommend a better approach for me to do that? Or is there something obvious that I missed?

Here are the code snippets:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import *


class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'new_task_text', 'placeholder': 'Add new task'}),
        }
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def list_homepage(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()

    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(form.cleaned_data)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
        return redirect('/list/home')

    context = {
        'page_title': 'Todo list',
        'tasks': tasks,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'tasks/list.html', context)
```

form in template:

```
    <form method="POST", action="#"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.title }}
        <input class="submit" type="submit", value="Create task">
    </form>
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you share the form part of your template?

Comment: Of course, editing the post right away!

Comment: Your form only has the one field, presumably you can use `{{ form }}` instead of `{{form.title}}` but did you want to give it a go first?

Comment: using {{ form }} actually displays a booleanfield that indicates whether the task was done or not, which I think would be unnecessary to have while listing things to do ;) It also displays the dropdown menu to choose from the usernames list.

Comment: Then at the very least you need to add a `{{form.added_by}}` or is it the logged in user that is supposed to be added here?

Comment: Yes, what I want to do is that django automatically adds current user from request.

Answer (score 0):

Your form template only includes the title field, you either need to add the added_by field to this form, or add it in the view handling

```
{{ form.added_by }}
```

or

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TaskForm({**request.POST, **{"added_by": request.user}})
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the adding to the view? I'm still quite a newbie to Django and it's not that obvious for me where to actually implement the latter code slice.

Comment: @kczan - This replaces your current call to the form

Comment: Seems like we're almost there! Last problem is that now the form acts like a dictionary I think? And what I get for the title is ['some title'], instead of just some title. Same goes to the form cleaned data in the console, {'title': "['some title']", 'completed': False, 'added_by': <User: username>}